# Full width slider in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slider

Okay, so i need a slider which is in a normal page to span across the whole screen.
The wrapper and all other elements is 960px max-width so thats how far the slider goes.
If i change these, the whole site will become messed up.

Im using Wordpress 3.5 with Twentytwelve theme as parent.

**SLIDER:** http://rocketplugins.com/wordpress-slider-plugin/

This is the only code i use in the post. So i guess i need to make the post wider?
    [slider id='32' name='']

Comment: can you provide side link or some code?

Comment: Done! Really dont know how to explain better

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about the product that your link explains but you will need to edit your page template.

There will be a content div (the one with max-width set). your new div, the one for the new slider, needs to be above it. I made a [page layout fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WebEnvelopment/CW7sd/) just for you.

HTML

```
<div class="newdiv">Slider here</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>Your WordPress post stuff here</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content{max-width:960px; height: 800px; background: #D3D3D3; margin: 0 auto;}
.newdiv{width:100%; height:200px; background:#BADA55;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by

```
<div id="slider">[slider id='32' name='']</div>
```

and

```
#slider {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 563px;
display: block;
}
```

Its not the best solution. But it works!